# Как получить кол-во знаков после запятой без использование строк?

Tags: c++, c, float, double

Для создания условия в своей программе мне нужно как-то посчитать, **сколько значащих символов стоит после запятой.** Запрещено использовать/преобразовывать что-либо в string.

Comment: Напишите преобразование числа в строку вручную, потом выкинете все лишнее (собственно строку) ...

Comment: Значащие символы после запятой во float так просто не посчитать, и делается это не строкой, а алгоритмически (см. IEEE754, если по уму)

Comment: А чего вы заминусовали парня? Это очень сложная задача.

Comment: Даже идей нет, может правда попробовать через сдвиги в IEEE754... Непонятно в каком направлении двигаться

Comment: Идея тут стандартная, деление на степени основания и нахождение остатков. Но есть некоторые но...

Comment: @rotabor за отсутствие внятного условия вопроса (и, например, примеров) заминусовали.

Comment: Павел, вы лучше сразу сознайтесь, это учебная задача (очень похоже) или вы что-то там себе такое напридумывали (называется проблема XY). что вылилось вот в это? Если это у вас какой-то хитрый алгоритм решения другой задачи, то лучше начать с неё.

Comment: Есть такой алгоритм: преобразовываем вещественное число в непрерывную дробь. В непрерывной дроби отыскиваем коэффициент больше некоторого порога (порог надо будет определить). Хвост дроби вместе в этим коэффициентом отбрасываем. По обрезанной  непрерывной дроби восстанавливаем десятичную дробь как рациональное число. В нём считаем количество знаков после запятой.

Comment: А вообще "число знаков после запятой" не нужно ни для каких задач кроме оформительских и бухгалтерских. Рассказывайте, какую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c) код printf. Там в функции `fmt_fp()` производится печать с заданной точностью (см. описание форматов в man fprintf). У меня складывается впечатление, что без вывода во внутренний строковый буфер вам не обойтись, поскольку для вашей задачи (как я ее понял) потребуется вычислить дробную часть с максимальной точностью и отбросить все младшие нули. Вы, конечно, можете повторить у себя  фрагменты этого очевидно не тривиального кода, но лично я (на практике) просто вызывал бы `sprintf(buf, "%.18g", x);` и смотрел на `buf[]`

Comment: @avp "без вывода во внутренний строковый буфер вам не обойтись" - int[] вполне заменяет строковый буфер. Нужно оставить цифру цифрой (0..9), а не добавлять к ней 48, чтобы получить код соотвествующего символа.

Comment: @rotabor, можно и в char[] писать цифры, а не их ascii коды. Суть дела это не меняет

Comment: @avp, Почему именно `18`?

Comment: @wololo, насколько помню это максимум десятичных цифр, что влезают в мантиссу (или только 17?)

Answer (score 0):

В строку-то преобразовывать точно не требуется, но это не главная проблема.

Сразу нужно уточнить вопрос: в какой системе счисления? В десятичной? Скорее всего, да. И тут начинаются проблемы.

Дело в том, что в памяти числа хранятся в двоичной системе (большинству из нас это известно), и многие числа, точно выраженные в десятичных дробях, не могут быть преобразованы в конечную двоичную дробь. Значит, если нам встретится, например, число 1,00000001 (условный пример), которое могло быть единицей, то мы не сможем это уверенно утверждать.

Далее, число нужно нормализовать, т. е. привести к E0 так, чтобы у него не появились лишние разряды после запятой.

Есть над чем подумать.

Будет обновлено.

Comment: `числа хранятся в двоичной системе, и многие из этих чисел не могут быть преобразованы в конечную десятичную дробь.` Пример?

Comment: *"многие из этих чисел не могут быть преобразованы в конечную десятичную дробь"* Нет, наоборот. Некоторые десятичные дроби не представимы как конечные двоичные, но все двоичные представимы как десятичные.

Comment: Да, немного попутал, или не так выразил мысль.

Answer (score 0):

Знакомая задача, и решать её нужно иначе.
Умножить число на отрицательную десятичную степень, получим целое число от единицы до 15. Дык вот если целое число больше девяти - то десятичная степень числа посчитана с ошибкой - нужно прибавить 1.
А дальше можно получить любое необходимое количество цифр, просто первое число отделяем запятой. https://godbolt.org/z/EKrxzEE1W
Строка 343 - предмет разговора.
Строка 385 - char txt[] = "9.9e-4"; - место для опытов.